# How can I manually document Swagger datamodel for a JAX-RS parameter?

Tags: java, swagger

### Context

Let's say that I have a simple data class in Java:

```java
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

*Note: in practice, I use [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) to generate this, but am showing a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) here for the sake of simplicity.*

To document the model of the `GET` response, even if the return type is `Response`, I can refer to the class in [`@ApiOperation`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.html):

```java
@GET
@ApiOperation(response = Person.class)
public Response getPerson() {
    return Response.ok(new Person("Julien", 28)).build();
}
```

Based on that, Swagger will document this correctly:

> Model:
>
> ```
> Person {
>   name (string),
>   age (number)
> }
> ```
>
> Example value:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "string",
>   "age": 0
> }
> ```

To document the model of the `POST` body, I use the class directly in the code, Swagger finds it and documents it as desired:

```java
@POST
@ApiOperation(response = Person.class)
public Response addPerson(Person newPerson) {
    return Response.ok(store.insert(newPerson)).build();
}
```

### Problem

I want to support partial updates as well. I cannot use the POJO itself, because all fields are mandatory in the POJO, I rely on that to get safe checks and clear error messages when invalid JSON is sent to e.g. the `POST` method.

In my actual use-case, my datamodel contains maps. I want users to be able to specify a certain key in the update and set the value to `null`, to delete elements from an existing maps.

I chose to support `PATCH` requests where the body is typed as a plain `JsonNode`. That allows any JSON to be received by my server and I can apply the updates as I wish.

```java
@PATCH
@Path("/{name}")
@ApiOperation(response = Person.class)
public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("name") String name, JsonNode update) {
    return Response.ok(store.update(name, update)).build();
}
```

I'm happy with the result, except that Swagger now documents the partial update's model with the properties of the `JsonNode` Java object:

> Model:
>
> ```
> JsonNode {
>   array (boolean, optional),
>   null (boolean, optional),
>   number (boolean, optional),
>   float (boolean, optional),
>   pojo (boolean, optional),
>   valueNode (boolean, optional),
>   containerNode (boolean, optional),
>   object (boolean, optional),
>   missingNode (boolean, optional),
>   nodeType (string, optional) = ['ARRAY', 'BINARY', 'BOOLEAN', 'MISSING', 'NULL', 'NUMBER', 'OBJECT', 'POJO', 'STRING'],
>   integralNumber (boolean, optional),
>   floatingPointNumber (boolean, optional),
>   short (boolean, optional),
>   int (boolean, optional),
>   long (boolean, optional),
>   double (boolean, optional),
>   bigDecimal (boolean, optional),
>   bigInteger (boolean, optional),
>   textual (boolean, optional),
>   boolean (boolean, optional),
>   binary (boolean, optional)
> }
> ```
>
> Example value:
>
> ```
> {
>   "array": true,
>   "null": true,
>   "number": true,
>   "float": true,
>   "pojo": true,
>   "valueNode": true,
>   "containerNode": true,
>   "object": true,
>   "missingNode": true,
>   "nodeType": "ARRAY",
>   "integralNumber": true,
>   "floatingPointNumber": true,
>   "short": true,
>   "int": true,
>   "long": true,
>   "double": true,
>   "bigDecimal": true,
>   "bigInteger": true,
>   "textual": true,
>   "boolean": true,
>   "binary": true
> }
> ```

I would like to specify in my code that the model is like `Person`, so that the example given in the Swagger UI is more relevant. I did try `@ApiImplicitParams`:

```java
@PATCH
@Path("/{name}")
@ApiOperation(response = Person.class)
@ApiImplicitParams({
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "update", dataTypeClass = Person.class)
})
public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("name") String name, JsonNode update) {
    return Response.ok(store.update(name, update)).build();
}
```

That did not make any difference. Swagger still documents `JsonNode` itself. The documentation for [`@ApiImplicitParams`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html) mentions:

> While [ApiParam](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) is bound to a JAX-RS parameter, method or field, this allows you to manually define a parameter in a fine-tuned manner. This is the only way to define parameters when using Servlets or other non-JAX-RS environments.

Since I am using JAX-RS, this might mean that I cannot use `@ApiImplicitParams`, but [`@ApiParam`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) does not provide anything to override the class.

How can I specify manually the datamodel of a JAX-RS parameter that is detected by Swagger automatically?

Comment: '*PATCH requests where the body is typed as a plain JsonNode*'. Why do you do this? Why not use `Person`?

Comment: @LutzHorn `Person` is annotated so that all fields are mandatory. I rely on that so that I get safe checks and clear error messages when invalid JSON is given to e.g. the `POST` method.

Another advantage of `JsonNode` that is not visible in my toy-example is that I use `null` values in Maps to mark that a certain value should be removed from the map...

Comment: @LutzHorn sorry for the inconvenience, I've completed the question. My motivation to simplify as much as possible is that I am not asking for other ways to support partial updates. I want to know more generally, how one can override the body's datamodel that is detected by Swagger automatically.

Comment: Do you use just the core swagger or a wrapper lib? Which version?

Comment: As a workaround, can you have another class with the same fields as Person, but where the fields are not mandatory - call it PersonPatch, or something like that.  It leads to duplication, but might help to express the intent better than allowing any JsonNode in the PATCH request.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I am fine using any version of core swagger - if something existed in an older version than the one I use, or if it was introduced more recently, I can easily change my version. Any answer that works will make me happy, regardless of the Swagger core version.

Comment: @RichardNeish True, that would work very well. I was hoping that Swagger allows me with an annotation to take care both of expressing intent in the code and documenting the datamodel in Swagger correctly.

Maybe instead of exploring what Swagger can do, I should look into how Immutables can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this answer to make it somewhat generic for better understanding of `@ApiImplicitParams`.

You would have to use `@ApiImplicitParams` for wrapping the parameters as you wish to save in the documentation.
`@ApiImplicitParam` has many not-so-obvious benefits, like to pass in extra header param without adding it as a method param or in your case wrap the the params so as to make them some sense.

For your problem, you would have to use `@ApiImplicitParam` along with `paramType = "body"` as you want to make changes in the body, similarly `paramType = "head"` if you wanted changes in header.

You can also control the mandatory fields in `@ApiImplicitParam` with property `required = true/false`.

As stated earlier, you can pass a param without having it in the method param, you can control its value using the property `value = "required value"`.

You can also control the allowable values in `@ApiImplicitParam` using comma seperated values. Eg.`allowableValues = "no-cache, no-store"`.

Answer (score 2):

I was on the right track with `@ApiImplicitParam` and I think I got it working the way I want, now:

```java
@PATCH
@Path("/{name}")
@ApiOperation(response = Person.class)
@ApiImplicitParams({
  @ApiImplicitParam(paramType = "body", dataTypeClass = ExchangeConfiguration.class)
})
public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("name") String name, @ApiParam(hidden = true) JsonNode update) {
    return Response.ok(store.update(name, update)).build();
}
```

Configuring a name was not mandatory, but `paramType` seems to be required. Using `paramType = "body"` makes Swagger document the implicit parameter correctly. That would cause the body to be documented twice; we can hide the automatically generated version with the wrong model, using `@ApiParam(hidden = true)`.

With the code above, the documentation looks exactly as I wanted, and the code continues to behave correctly.

Thanks all for the help!